# Autofac named service is not found in Web API Controller using attribute (Autofac.Extras.Attributed)

Tags: autofac, asp.net-web-api

(Note: This is a simplified example intended to highlight the issue I'm seeing.)

I have a service I'm trying to register as a named service as follows:

```
builder.Register(new MyService()).Named<IMyService>("Test").SingleInstance();
```

I would have expected to be able to use this service in the constructor of my API Controller:

```
public TestController([WithKey("Test")] IMyService myService)
{
}
```

However, an exception gets thrown:

```
None of the constructors found with
'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
'TestController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'IMyService myService' of constructor 'Void
.ctor(IMyService)'.
```

The same code as above works when I replace the .Named() call with a .As():

```
builder.Register(new MyService()).As<IMyService>().SingleInstance();

public TestController(IMyService myService)
{
}
```

It *also* seems to work when I keep the .Named() call, but *add* the .As() call to it first:

```
builder.Register(new MyService()).As<IMyService>().Named<IMyService>("Test")
    .SingleInstance();

public TestController([WithKey("Test")] IMyService myService)
{
}
```

Any ideas on why this behaves as it does? Am I doing something wrong in how I register named services?

Answer (score 0):

From [the Autofac wiki:](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AttributeMetadata)

That component will require you to register a keyed service with the specified name. You'll also need to register the component with the filter so the container knows to look for it.

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Register the keyed service to consume
builder.RegisterType<MyArtwork>().Keyed<IArtwork>("Painting");

// Specify WithAttributeFilter for the consumer
builder.RegisterType<ArtDisplay>().As<IDisplay>().WithAttributeFilter();
...
var container = builder.Build();
```

Notice the `WithAttributeFilter()`. Try to add this to your `RegisterControllers()` call.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no `WithAttributeFilter()` method I can add to the end of `builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TestController)));`

Comment: It's an extension method from the `AutofacAttributeExtensions` class. Be sure to import the `Autofac.Extras.Attributed` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [WithName] attribute not [WithKey]